# Resource Versioning with configuration xml-based (Spring)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, xml-parsing

I'm trying to use the [VersionResourceResolver](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-config-static-resources) in order to prevent old js and css to be cached. Currently I'm using XML-Based Configuration for my Spring. I just copied this code:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/public-resources/">
    <mvc:resource-chain>
        <mvc:resource-cache/>
        <mvc:resolvers>
            <mvc:version-resolver>
                <mvc:content-version-strategy patterns="/**"/>
            </mvc:version-resolver>
        </mvc:resolvers>
    </mvc:resource-chain>
</mvc:resources>
```

and placed it inside my xml called by the DispatcherServlet in order to start my web application. After placing this code in my servlet.xml I have something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">



    <context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/application.properties" />

    <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    </bean>

    <mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:argument-resolvers>
            <bean class="org.springframework.mobile.device.DeviceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver"/>
        </mvc:argument-resolvers>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/">
        <mvc:resource-chain>
            <mvc:resource-cache />
            <mvc:resolvers>
                <mvc:version-resolver>
                    <mvc:content-version-strategy patterns="/**"/>
                </mvc:version-resolver>
            </mvc:resolvers>
        </mvc:resource-chain>
    </mvc:resources>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/sources/**" location="/sources/" />

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator">
        <property name="proxyTargetClass" value="true" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="localeResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="pt_BR" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Eclipse tells me that are 2 errors in my servlet.xml:

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'mvc:resource-cache'. One of '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc":resolvers, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc":transformers}' is expected.
cvc-complex-type.4: Attribute 'resource-cache' must appear on element 'mvc:resource-chain'.
```

I don't know what could be since I'm using the last version of the mvc.xsd.
If anyone can help to find my mistake I'm grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, so a college of mine already solved this one. The [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-config-static-resources) is wrong, the right way to use Resource Versioning with XML-Based Configuration is:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/public-resources/">
    <mvc:resource-chain resource-cache="true">
        <mvc:resolvers>
            <mvc:version-resolver>
                <mvc:content-version-strategy patterns="/**"/>
            </mvc:version-resolver>
        </mvc:resolvers>
    </mvc:resource-chain>
</mvc:resources>
```

Comment: Have you created Spring ticket to ask them update the docs? That would be helpful.

Comment: Good idea, i did not thought about! I'll do it!